# Ways to use common css styles for all other css class

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have following css class

```
.class1
{
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    height: 21px;
    border-color: #F5E0C4;
}

.class2
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 3px 3px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2ccab;
    border-color: #F5E0C4;
}

.class3
{
   border-color: #F5E0C4;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 14px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,#314d8a,#93aee8);
}
```

here all above classes are using same `border-color: #F5E0C4;` as this border-color is repeating in classes; I want to keep it separate and use commonly for all above classes, so if any point of time I want to change the colour I should change at only one place.

I googled for this but I got only one approach that says apply multiple css class on element like this.

```
.classBorder
{
  border-color: #F5E0C4;
}

<div class="class1 classBorder"> 
</div>
<div class="class2 classBorder"> 
</div>
<div class="class3 classBorder"> 
</div>
```

Please suggest me any other approach if it is possible.

Comment: It's a pretty good approach if you're using vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to go with the CSS3 Variables. Something like:

```
:root {
    --main-border-color: #F5E0C4;
}

.class1
{
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    height: 21px;
    border-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

Comment: this works fine in Chrome but does not work in IE .. do u have any idea  for IE as well

Comment: Unfortunately it is not supported by IE (only edge). But the answer from @SreenathPG should work in all browsers

Answer (score 4):

You can use LESS also

```
.classBorder
{
  border-color: #F5E0C4;
}

.class1
{
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    height: 21px;
    .classBorder;
}

.class2
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 3px 3px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2ccab;
    .classBorder;
}

.class3
{
   .classBorder;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 14px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,#314d8a,#93aee8);
}
```

Refer It - [Less Link](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: thanks @Gattbha I am using bootstrap as well in my application, does this compatible with bootstrap? and is this free ware?

Comment: for that, you need to add less support bootstrap file..please refer it - http://www.web-development-institute.com/step-step-guide-using-less-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

You can select all three classes like that:

```
.class1, .class2,  .class3 {    
  border-color: #F5E0C4;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select all classes, simply:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3 { border-color: #F5E0C4; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could simply use something like this:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3 {
 border-color: #F5E0C4;
}
    .class1 {
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    height: 21px;
}

.class2
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 3px 3px 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2ccab;
}

.class3
{
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 14px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,#314d8a,#93aee8);
}
```